# RMS value of a signal with a DC offset in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

```
t = 0:0.001:1;
y1 = 400 * sin(2*pi*20*t);
y2 = 200 + 400 * sin(2*pi*20*t);
plot(t,y1)
hold on
plot(t,y2,'-g')
grid on;
rms_y1 = sqrt(mean(y1.^2)) 
rms_y2 = sqrt(mean(y2.^2))
```

In the above MATLAB code there are two signals `y1` and `y2`.

`y1` is a sinusoidal signal 20 Hz with 400V amplitude.

`y2` is a signal which is nothing but `y1` + 200V DC offset.

So I was thinking the "rms of `y2`" would be equal to "rms of `y1` + 200". Since rms of a constant is the constant itself.

But rms of `y1` is 282.7014; and rms of `y2` turns out to be 346.2948 (not 282 + 200).

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: you are possibly confusing **RMS** with **variance**.  These two signals do have the same variance, but their RMS also depends on their DC points. Hence the computation is right according to $X_{RMS} = \sqrt { \frac{1}{T} { \int_{0}^{T}{x^2(t) dt}   }  }$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RMS values don't simply add up. The RMS value of $N$ discrete samples $x[n]$ (assuming $0\le n<N$) is

$$x_{RMS}=\sqrt{\frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}x^2[n]}\tag{1}$$

Now if you have $y[n]=x[n]+c$ with some constant $c$, the RMS value of $y[n]$ is

$$\begin{align}y_{RMS}&=\sqrt{\frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}y^2[n]}\\&=\sqrt{\frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}(x[n]+c)^2}\\&=\sqrt{\frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}(x^2[n]+2cx[n]+c^2)}\\&=\sqrt{\frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}x^2[n]+\frac{2c}{N}\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}x[n]+\frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}c^2}\tag{2}\end{align}$$

If we define the mean value of $x[n]$ as

$$m_x=\frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}x[n]\tag{3}$$

then from $(2)$ the square of the RMS value of $y[n]$ can be expressed as

$$y^2_{RMS}=x^2_{RMS}+2cm_x+c^2\tag{4}$$

So if you assume that the mean of $x[n]$ equals zero, the *squares* of the RMS values add up:

$$y^2_{RMS}=x^2_{RMS}+c^2\tag{5}$$

You can easily verify Eq. $(5)$ using your example:

$$(282.7014)^2+(200)^2=(346.2948)^2\tag{6}$$

Comment: so the eq. sqrt(mean(y.^2))  is correct ? thanks

Comment: @user16307: Yes, it is (for real-valued vectors), but there's actually also the Matlab command 'rms'.

Comment: mine is Matlab 6 it doesnt have that function

Answer (score 0):

Your intuition is wrong.

If your `y2` was more like:

```
y2 = 200*sign(sin(2*pi*20*t)) + 400 * sin(2*pi*20*t);
```

then your intuition would be correct.

The issue is that adding a constant value to the sinusoid *adds* to the sinusoid's RMS value when the sinusoid is positive (and the offset is positive) but *subtracts* from the RMS value when the sinusoid is negative.

Making the DC offset increase the RMS value in both polarities will get you what you expect.